# Export multiple QGIS layers in one shot

Tags: qgis

Is there a way we can export multiple layers in QGIS as ESRI shapefiles in on shot?

[image: QGIS_screenshot]

Comment: You can use the "Save Vector Features to File" processing algorithm with "Run as Batch Process..." otherwise there most likely exists a plugin already to do that or you can use a python script

Comment: "Batch Vector Layer Saver" is the name of the plugin, it took me about 10 seconds to find it, you should do some research before asking a question on this site especially

Comment: That's right. I should have done some research before posting here. And btw, I installed the plugin "Batch Vector Layer Saver" and it worked 100%. Thanks man !

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to some older questions here in stackexchange, I managed to build a very simple python script who let me export all the layers as an ESRI shapefiles:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter

pathToFile = r"C:\\Users\_M92\\Desktop\\Output_Test\\"
for vLayer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer, pathToFile + vLayer.name(), "utf-8", vLayer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )
```

and also as a csv files:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter

pathToFile = r"C:\\Users\_M92\\Desktop\\Output_Test\\"
for vLayer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer, pathToFile + vLayer.name() + ".csv", "utf-8", vLayer.crs(), driverName="CSV" )
```

Comment: There is only one issue : the output layers are saved in \Desktop and not in \Desktop\Output_Test !

Comment: I get this error after adding the slash :

 pathToFile = r"C:\Users\_M92\Desktop\Output_Test\"
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Now, I put a double slash and it worked : r"C:\\Users\\_M92\\Desktop\\Output_Test\\", thanks man !